# MS Access 2010: Unrecognized database format on network locations

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

In my organization, all Access databases with a table containing data stored in the database on a shared location generate the error 'Unrecognized database format'. If we make and fill the database locally, everything works just fine. Once we save the database to a shared file location, the error 'Unrecognized database format' appears and the database starts repairing itself (unsuccessfully).

If the database doesn't contain data but is connected to a external data source, for example a .txt file or sharepoint list, the database keeps working fine.
The databases are .accdb files but if we make a new database as .mdb file the problem doesn't disappear.

I found several other questions regarding the error 'Unrecognized database format' but none concerning this error when saving on a network location.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are hit by the now three(!) year old *lease bug*.

Daniel has wrapped it up nicely, including the options you (don't) have:

[Access – Bug – Database is in an Unrecognized Format](https://www.devhut.net/2018/06/13/access-bug-database-is-in-an-unrecognized-format/)

The main issue is, that the way newer Windows versions work may not be compatible with the way Access shares an Access database.

As this is touching both the core of Windows file sharing and the core of the Access database engine, there is no simple fix, as the three year delay clearly indicates. What we currently know is only, that Microsoft is still working to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, given the number of other bugs and workarounds in MS Access I encountered so far I think we can give up hope for a solution.

Comment: Not sure what those bugs and workarounds could be. Apart from this _lease bug_, bugs are extremely few and minor. If many workarounds are needed, Access probably isn't the right tool for your task; if so, turn to _Visual Studio_.